# Query Animation Function Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a website with multiple boxes and I want to create a function for the animations so I don’t have to add them to each hover box as some have different animations included.

For some reason I cannot call the animation in the box, if I copy the function code and place in the box it works fine but can get it working calling it from the function.

```
function aniIn() {
    $(".br-t", this).stop().animate({ "width": "100%" }, 500, "easeOutQuint" ),
}

function aniOut() {
    $(".br-t", this).stop().animate({ "width": "0"}, 900, "easeOutQuint" ),
}

$("a#box01").hover(function() {
        $("#background").fadeIn(500);
        aniIn();
    }, function() {
        $("#background").stop().fadeOut(900);
        aniOut()
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="box01" title="box"></a>
```

Any help would be great.

TJ.

Comment: What do you mean by `box` ?

Comment: You have used 'this' in your functions. That's why it is not working. You need to pass 'this' to both functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
function aniIn(current) {  

 $(".br-t", current).stop().animate({ "width": "100%" }, 500, "easeOutQuint" ),
}

function aniOut(current) {
    $(".br-t", current).stop().animate({ "width": "0"}, 900, "easeOutQuint" ),
}

$("a#box01").hover(function() {
        $("#background").fadeIn(500);
        aniIn(this);
    }, function() {
        $("#background").stop().fadeOut(900);
        aniOut(this);
});
```